# How to find number in text with pattern and change it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match

I have some text in `text input` that contain numbers with a pattern in whole of text and want to find all number with this pattern and recalculate and replace in text

```
 .... val="2xf" 
 .........
 vc="2.6xf"
 ...... 
 value="1.2xf"
 .....
```

find all number with `xf` and change it with a formula 

for  example:
find all matched pattern and replace by sum with `5` 
`2xf` =>change to `7xf` ,  (2+5=7) 
`2.6xf` change to `7.6xf` ,  (2.6+5=7.6) 
`1.2xf` change to `6.2xf` ,  (1.2+5=6.2)

```
 .... val="7xf" 
 .........
 vc="7.6xf"
 ...... 
 value="6.2xf"
```

how can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem with a help of **RegEx** and **replace** method of String object:

```
value = value.replace(/(\d+)(.*xf)/g, function(_, number, other) {
    return (+number + 5).toString() + other;
});
```